# How can I google-charts integer annotation

Tags: google-visualization

I am using "google charts" and everything is really cool .
I just have a problem with the fact that I want the values in the columns to be displayed as whole numbers and not decimals.

With the values in the Axis is not a problem :

```
var options = {
    title: "Faktury w SLA",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    hAxis: {viewWindow: {min:0, max:3}},        
    bar: {groupWidth: "75%"},   
                
                legend: {position: 'bottom'},
                titlePosition: 'out',
                axisTitlesPosition: 'out',
                        series: {
                    0: {color: '#008000',format: '#',targetAxisIndex: 0},
                    1: {color: '#d6d6c2',format: '#',targetAxisIndex: 1}
                },
                
                vAxes: {
                    // Adds titles to each axis.
                    0: {title: '% W SLA2',format:'',minValue:0, maxValue:100,textStyle: {color: '#009900'}},
                    1: {title: 'Ilość w SLA2',format: '#',minValue:0}
                }
  };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5BhY.png)

Ps.
It is about the second column ( not green )